# UWP Ink strokes sent to WCF service. Black/Blank image result

Tags: uwp, base64, blob, stroke

I'm not sure how to ask this.  I have a UWP app that captures ink strokes as BLOBs and sends them to a service that decodes them back to PNG or other image formats.

Originally the ink strokes worked fine.  I was able to capture the ink and convert it back to an image.  But lately I've noticed the inks strokes are still saved to BLOBs, just not ones I can decode.

These are the type of BLOBs I am used to seeing...

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB0QAAAUvCAYAAAAhI1YPAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c[...]FOl/H86CXiFEsRU5ErkJggg==
```

And these are the BLOBs that I see now...

```
R0lGODlhjgHCAHAAACH5BAEAAAMALAAAAACOAcIAgQAAA/wAA/gAAAAL/nI+py+0[...]AAAAAAAAKjUQlzgAAAAA7
```

I've tried saving the images in various format types while using

> Convert.FromBase64String()

to convert the BLOB to a manageable byte array, but nothing has worked so far.
I know the new BLOBs are valid because some online base64 decoders are able to produce the image I expect.  Has anyone seen these types of BLOBs and know how to decode them correctly?

**UPDATE (by request)**

```
    public static void SampleForStackOverflow()
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
        byte[] bytes2 = Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAATCAYAAACUef2IAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAACJSURBVDhP3ZFbCsAgDAS197+zRRLw0V2TqF8dKIKYcd2mGKXIZ5N1dTAL83L20fU60619qj4RS8vOD2JfdwISV5pcq4hIVzTPRsf9k8fnCyInYjRQQfv4rG7yrnx850ni885VzLrav2ASrkSsHjSTWdITxAk6jv44jCGJpm+hnOmsC+688pek9AJuQCoVPgMNJwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
        Image image, image2;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(bytes2))
        {
            image2 = Image.FromStream(ms2, true);
        }
        image.Save("image.png");
        image2.Save("image2.png");

        if (image != null)
        { image.Dispose(); }
        if (image2 != null)
        { image2.Dispose(); }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

The "R01GOD1" string was converted to an image and then encoded back into a "iVBOR" string using the site "http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image"

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a code sample of the process I use in my UWP for converting an inkstrokecontainer into a base64string that I can then send to my service.

```
    private async static Task<string> WriteInkToBase64String(Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStrokeContainer inkContainer)
    {
        byte[] data;
        Stream s = null;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream imras = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        try
        {
            await inkContainer.SaveAsync(imras);
            s = imras.AsStream();
            s.Position = 0;
            s.CopyTo(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        finally {
            ms.Dispose();
            if (s != null)
                s.Dispose();
            imras.Dispose();

        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share  [mcve]

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
Both Base64 string formats work.  The latest format produced by UWP applications can only be read as `Bitmap`.  If you try to read in Ink Strokes as `Image`, then you get a black box.

```
public static Bitmap ConvertBase64ToBitmap(string base64String)
{
    byte[] stringBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(stringBytes))
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

If you don't want to deal with Bitmaps on the server/service side, then you can convert the ink as an image and freely save it as a byte array or base64 string or whatever else.

```
public static async Task<string> WriteInkAsPngToBase64(InkStrokeContainer ink)
{
    SoftwareBitmap sbmp;
    byte[] byteResults = null;
    string base64String = null;
    // inStream is the IRandomAccessStream with the GIF data (filled from InkStrokeContainer.SaveAsync)
    // outStream is an IRandomAcccessStream to save the PNG data
    //                                                                              -Rob Caplan - MSFT
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream inStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream outStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await ink.SaveAsync(inStream);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inStream);
    sbmp = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, outStream);
    encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(sbmp);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    byteResults = new byte[outStream.Size];
    using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(outStream.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)outStream.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(byteResults);
    }
    base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteResults);
    return base64String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For decoding `Base64` string within UWP, you could use [`CryptographicBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer) class to decode or encode data.

```
IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String("R0l==")
```

Then, you could use the following code to converter `buffer` to `bitmapimage`.

```
using (IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = buffer2.AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream())
{
    var bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
    await bitmapimage.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
     {
         image1.Source = bitmapimage;
     });
}
```

For more detail you could refer [**Encode and decode data**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/encode-and-decode-data) document.

Comment: Decoding within the UWP does not help my situation.  It needs to be decoded in a WCF service that is located in another server.  Or the BLOB needs to be encoded in the format that is expected.  I have tried testing the code sample you provided in a console app and WCF service, but it is clear I don't have access to the required DLLs that appear to only be available within UWPs.

Comment: @StoicDeveloper I don't know why you want decode in your service. In general, encode and  decode process will be done in client app and the service only use to store the base64 string.

Comment: Are you telling me you really can't see the use of being able to take strokes from an ink canvas, encode into manageable data that is then sent to a service, the service then decodes or sends the data to any other application that can then use the ink strokes as a record of the users' actions from the original canvas?

Comment: In any case, I know it can be done since an online tool has proven it is feasible to decode the new format and return a working image of  the ink.  I just need to know what inane hoops I need to jump through to get my application working again.

Comment: I mean you could decode in clent that will keep data consistency.

Comment: You could decode in client.  And my app does decode the ink strokes when a user returns to the app to look over what they have written.  But in this case, I need the data to be visible outside the app for record management.  If a source of data was originally able to be used by other applications but the source now locks that data to make it unusable on any other application framework, I would classify that as a bug.